# Mapping errors in maven project

Tags: jersey

I am pretty new in restful application and maven ones. I have tried to create a web dynamic project application in maven using hibernate. But i face a 404 error problem. I think the problem is somewhere in my web.xml file. I would really appreciate if anyone could help. Below is my full code.

MyResource.java

```
import com.crud.dao.EmployeeDAO;


@Path("/employees")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        List employees = dao.getEmployees();
        return employees;
    }


    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response addEmployee(Employee emp){
        emp.setName(emp.getName());
        emp.setAge(emp.getAge());

        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        dao.addEmployee(emp);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/update/{id}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response updateEmployee(@PathParam("id") int id, Employee emp){
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        int count = dao.updateEmployee(id, emp);
        if(count==0){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response deleteEmployee(@PathParam("id") int id){
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        int count = dao.deleteEmployee(id);
        if(count==0){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.crud.dao;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

EmployeeDAO.java

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

    public void addEmployee(Employee bean){
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();        
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        addEmployee(session,bean);        
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    private void addEmployee(Session session, Employee bean){
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        employee.setName(bean.getName());
        employee.setAge(bean.getAge());

        session.save(employee);
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();    
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        List<Employee> employees =  query.list();
        session.close();
        return employees;
    }

    public int deleteEmployee(int id) {
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "delete from Employee where id = :id";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setInteger("id",id);
        int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowCount);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return rowCount;
    }

    public int updateEmployee(int id, Employee emp){
         if(id <=0)  
               return 0;  
         Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "update Employee set name = :name, age=:age where id = :id";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setInteger("id",id);
            query.setString("name",emp.getName());
            query.setInteger("age",emp.getAge());
            int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowCount);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return rowCount;
    }
}
```

SessionUtil.java

```
package com.crud.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionUtil {

    private static SessionUtil instance=new SessionUtil();
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionUtil getInstance(){
            return instance;
    }

    private SessionUtil(){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        Session session =  getInstance().sessionFactory.openSession();

        return session;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.22.1 2015-10-07 10:54:41"/>
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:hint="This is simplified WADL with user and core resources only. To get full WADL with extended resources use the query parameter detail. Link: http://localhost:8080/jersey-webapp/webapi/application.wadl?detail=true"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/jerseypro/webapi/">
        <resource path="/employees">
            <method id="getEmployee" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseypro</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Define the ResourceConfig class -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.crud.jerseypro.MyResource</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Pro</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</application>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jerseypro</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>jerseypro</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <phase>
  Employee
  </phase>
  <goals>
  <goal>java</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <mainClass>com.crud.dao.Employee</mainClass>
  <arguments>
  <argument>
  myArg1
  </argument>
  <argument>myArg2</argument>
  </arguments>
  </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious thing is that you have the servlet mappings incorrect.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseypro</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Define the ResourceConfig class -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.crud.jerseypro.MyResource</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Pro</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

You have your servlet name to be jerseypro but your servlet mapping is mapped to Jersey Pro. This should have given you an error on startup. Check your java logs to see what is going on.

Also your maven project configuration is not going to work. It looks like it is going to try and start the Employee class but that class does not have static main Method. This is also not going to work. Look into the tomcat7 maven plugin. It will start an http server to host your jersey code for testing. You can start it with mvn `tomcat7:run`. That should get you going.

Comment: I don't know what you changed. Did you add the tomcat plugin. This `com.crud.dao.Employee` is not a main class and will not do anything. You are not starting any kind of web server in you pom that I see. How are you starting the application?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly my problem. Thank you so much. You were very helpful